# How to say: "instead of" + verb

Tags: перевод

Consider the following example:

> Instead of going to the ball.

I know "вместо" means instead but I don't know how to translate "of doing something". Maybe there is another way of saying the same thing.

Comment: instead = вместо

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Instead of` + `doing something` translate as `вместо того, чтобы` + `что-то делать/сделать`.

'Instead of going to the ball'. -> "Вместо того, чтобы идти/пойти на бал."

Answer (score 5):

The answer of @eugen is 100% valid, I just want to add yet another translation pattern which can be used in context of colloquial speech when there's some verb in imperative mood: чем ["instead" part], лучше б/б лучше...

For example:

- Чем на бал ходить, ты б лучше подмела.
- Чем на велосипеде кататься, ты б лучше уроки сделала.

So, in some cases "instead of" can be translated this way, but, once again, the set of use cases is quite narrower than speaking of pattern provided in @eugens' answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can use verb-derived nouns.

"Вместо похода на бал Золушка весь вечер занималась уборкой."

Comment: Is it possible to say,in which cases exactly a verb-derived noun can be used?

Comment: @Olga по глаголу всегда можно определить завершённость/незавершённость, повторяемость/однократность действия, а по существительному без контекста — не всегда. Сравните: "Вместо уборки Золушка сбежала на бал". "Вместо того, чтобы убираться, ..." и "Вместо того, чтобы убраться, ..."

Comment: @КуЪ I don't see how it answers my question.