# "Вместо" or "взамен"

Tags: словоупотребление, выбор-слова

I found two translations for "**instead of**": **вместо** or **взамен**. What's the acceptable one for the following contexts?

I want to say for example that "I want red instead of blue, house instead of apartment". "I bought a fork instead of spoon.". Which of these two should I use?

N.b. I found here [this answer](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/how-to-say-instead-of-verb), but it deals with other question.

Answer (score 11):

**взамен** emphasizes replacing or changing one thing to another.

Я купил скутер **взамен** велосипеда. (I bought a scooter to replace a bike.)
He had the bike, but he bought the scooter to use it instead of the bike.

Я купил новую лампочку **взамен** старой. (I bought a new light bulb **to replace** old one.)

**вместо** means one instead of another.

Я купил скутер **вместо** велосипеда. (I planned to buy a bike, but I bought a scooter).

Answer (score 8):

What fits in your examples is **вместо**

**Взамен** is used when you (wish to) replace something you already possess as **заменить** means **to replace**

> Я поставил новый замок взамен старого

or (expect to) receive something in return for what you share or offer

> [Мы уважаем все клубы и ожидаем того же взамен](https://www.sport-express.ru/football/france/news/prezident-pszh-my-uvazhaem-vse-kluby-i-ozhidaem-togo-zhe-vzamen-1307685/)

Answer (score 3):

**Взамен** is typically about replacing something *for a reason*, e. g. the old thing is already (or expected to be) **gone** (lost or given/promised to somebody), **can't be used** anymore. The idea of **compensation** (finding a good replacement) is here:

> *Взамен* украденного/поломанного велосипеда он купил новый (или купил
>   мопед).
>
> Если ты отдашь мне эту редкую монету, я *взамен* дам тебе любую другую
>   (или окажу важную услугу).

**Вместо** has much wider meaning and is applicable to both things and actions (**instead** or **rather than** doing something).

> *Вместо* шляпы на ходу он надел сковороду.
>
> *Вместо* лампочки накаливания лучше поставить светодиодную.
>
> *Вместо* того, чтобы обратиться в полицию, он решил сам наказать обидчика.